# Java 8 Streams - Compare two Lists' object values and add value to new List?

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two `List`s containing objects of this class:

```
public class SchoolObj
{
    private String name;
    private String school;

    public SchoolObj()
    {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public SchoolObj(String nameStr, String schoolStr)
    {
        this.setName(nameStr);
        this.setSchool(schoolStr);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSchool()
    {
        return this.school;
    }

    public void setSchool(String school)
    {
        this.school = school;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.getName() + ' ' + this.getSchool();
    }
}
```

I want to compare the objects in those two lists by `name` and `school`. If they are equal I need to create a new `List` containing those `SchoolObj` objects which are found in both Lists.

I know we can use two `for` loops and do it is in the `createSharedListViaLoop` method below.

My question is, how can I accomplish the same thing with Java streams?

I tried with `createSharedListViaStream` below, but it is not working as expected.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<SchoolObj> listOne = new ArrayList<SchoolObj>();
        // TODO: Add sample data to listOne.
        listOne.add(new SchoolObj("nameA", "schoolX"));
        listOne.add(new SchoolObj("nameC", "schoolZ"));

        List<SchoolObj> listTwo = new ArrayList<SchoolObj>();
        // TODO: Add sample data to listTwo.
        listTwo.add(new SchoolObj("nameA", "schoolX"));
        listTwo.add(new SchoolObj("nameB", "schoolY"));

        // Print results from loop method.
        System.out.println("Results from loop method:");
        List<SchoolObj> resultsViaLoop = StreamTest.createSharedListViaLoop(listOne, listTwo);
        for (SchoolObj obj : resultsViaLoop)
        {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

        // Print results from stream method.
        System.out.println("Results from stream method:");
        List<SchoolObj> resultsViaStream = StreamTest.createSharedListViaStream(listOne, listTwo);
        for (SchoolObj obj : resultsViaStream)
        {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }

    public static List<SchoolObj> createSharedListViaLoop(List<SchoolObj> listOne, List<SchoolObj> listTwo)
    {
        List<SchoolObj> result = new ArrayList<SchoolObj>();

        for (SchoolObj one : listOne)
        {
            for (SchoolObj two : listTwo)
            {
                if (one.getName().equals(two.getName()) && one.getSchool().equals(two.getSchool()))
                {
                    result.add(one);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static List<SchoolObj> createSharedListViaStream(List<SchoolObj> listOne, List<SchoolObj> listTwo)
    {
        List<SchoolObj> listOneList = listOne.stream().filter(two -> listTwo.stream()
              .anyMatch(one -> one.getName().equals(two.getName()) && two.getSchool().equals(one.getSchool()))) 
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return listOneList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show, don't tell. Maybe your solution just needs a 1 character change.

Comment: Changes made, please recheck my question @Michael

Comment: @Vinay I moved your two implementations (the loop method and the stream method) into a class with a main method so the results can be compared. If you can add some sample data (see TODO items in the code), we will have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), which usually results in far more responses on this site.

Answer (score 18):

Let's run through each part of the code. First, `createSharedListViaStream`:

```
public static List<SchoolObj> createSharedListViaStream(List<SchoolObj> listOne, List<SchoolObj> listTwo)
{
    // We create a stream of elements from the first list.
    List<SchoolObj> listOneList = listOne.stream()
    // We select any elements such that in the stream of elements from the second list
    .filter(two -> listTwo.stream()
    // there is an element that has the same name and school as this element,
        .anyMatch(one -> one.getName().equals(two.getName()) 
            && two.getSchool().equals(one.getSchool())))
    // and collect all matching elements from the first list into a new list.
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // We return the collected list.
    return listOneList;
}
```

After running through the code, it does exactly what you want it to do. Now, let's run through `createSharedListViaLoop`:

```
public static List<SchoolObj> createSharedListViaLoop(List<SchoolObj> listOne, List<SchoolObj> listTwo)
{
    // We build up a result by...
    List<SchoolObj> result = new ArrayList<SchoolObj>();
    // going through each element in the first list,
    for (SchoolObj one : listOne)
    {
    // going through each element in the second list,
        for (SchoolObj two : listTwo)
        {
    // and collecting the first list's element if it matches the second list's element.
            if (one.getName().equals(two.getName()) && one.getSchool().equals(two.getSchool()))
            {
                result.add(one);
            }
        }
    }
    // We return the collected list
    return result;
}
```

So far, so good... right? In fact, your code in `createSharedListViaStream` is fundamentally correct; instead, it is your `createSharedListViaLoop` that may be causing discrepancies in output.

Think about the following set of inputs:
`List1 = [SchoolObj("nameA","SchoolX"), SchoolObj("nameC","SchoolZ")]`
`List2 = [SchoolObj("nameA","SchoolX"), SchoolObj("nameA","SchoolX"), SchoolObj("nameB","SchoolY")]`

Here, `createSharedListViaStream` will return the only element of the first list that appears in both lists: `SchoolObj("nameA","SchoolX")`. However, `createSharedListViaLoop` will return the following list: `[SchoolObj("nameA","SchoolX"),SchoolObj("nameA","SchoolX")]`. More precisely, `createSharedListViaLoop` will collect the correct object, but it will do so twice. I suspect this to be the reason for the output of `createSharedListViaStream` to be "incorrect" based on comparison to the output of `createSharedListViaLoop`.

The reason that `createSharedListViaLoop` does this duplication is based on the lack of termination of its inner for loop. Although we iterate over all elements of the first list to check if they are present in the second, finding a single match will suffice to add the element to the result. We can avoid redundant element addition by changing the inner loop to the following:

```
for (SchoolObj one : listOne)
    {
    for (SchoolObj two : listTwo)
    {
        if (one.getName().equals(two.getName()) && one.getSchool().equals(two.getSchool()))
        {
            result.add(one);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you don't want duplicate Objects in your list (by location in memory), you can use [distinct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) like so:

```
List<SchoolObj> result = ...;
result = result.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As a final caution, the above will keep the results distinct in the following scenario:

```
List<SchoolObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
SchoolObj duplicate = new SchoolObj("nameC", "schoolD");
listOne.add(duplicate);
listOne.add(duplicate);
list.stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println); 
// prints:
// nameC schoolD
```

However, it will not work in the following scenario, unless you override the [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method for SchoolObj:

```
List<SchoolObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
listOne.add(new SchoolObj("nameC", "schoolD"));
listOne.add(new SchoolObj("nameC", "schoolD"));
list.stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println); 
// prints (unless Object::equals overridden)
// nameC schoolD
// nameC schoolD
```

Answer (score 9):

You can filter in one list if contains in another list then collect.

```
List<SchoolObj> listCommon = listTwo.stream()
                                         .filter(e -> listOne.contains(e)) 
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You need to override `equals()` method in `SchoolObj` class. `contains()` method you will uses the `equals()` method to evaluate if two objects are the same.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof SchoolObj))
        return false;
    SchoolObj n = (SchoolObj) o;
    return n.name.equals(name) && n.school.equals(school);
}
```

---

But better solution is to use Set for one list and filter in another list to collect if contains in Set. `Set#contains` takes O(1) which is faster.

```
Set<SchoolObj> setOne = new HashSet<>(listOne);
List<SchoolObj> listCommon = listTwo.stream()
                                     .filter(e -> setOne.contains(e)) 
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You need to override `hashCode()` method also along with `equals()` in `SchoolObj` class for `Set#contains`.(assuming `name` and `school` can't be null)

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + name.hashCode();
    result = prime * result + school.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/27609#27609) you will get details how to override equals and hashCode in a better way

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had Two lists. I compared both lists having common emails and collected the objects like this:

```
List<TUsers> comparedUsersOnEmail = tUsers.stream().filter(o1 -> userR.stream()
      .anyMatch(o2->o2.getEmail().equals(o1.getEmail()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```