# Stream to compare two list by index

Tags: java, stream

I have 2 distinct lists: `List1` and `List2`, and I want to perform an action for each index where the elements have the same `getName()` value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    if (list1.get(i).getName().equals(list2.get(i).getName())) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this using Java streams?  I have tried the logic:

```
if (List1().stream().anymatch(x -> List2().stream().anymatch(y -> x.getName().equals(y.getName))))) {
    // TODO
}
```

This works, but first object(index) of `List1` is compared with every object(index) of `List2`.

What I need is first object(index) of `List1` to be compared with first of `List2`, second index to second and so on.
How to write this if logic using stream instead of for loop.

Comment: Please dont post code as images

Comment: Use an `IntStream` to generate the indices e.g. `IntStream.range(0, 5)`, then use `map`, `mapToObj` or `forEach` as appropriate and access `obj1.get(i)` and `obj2.get(i)`.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, a.length).mapToObj(i -> a[i].getName() == b[i].getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
` something like this?

Comment: What do you want after condition check. Are you going to store data in another list.
please be specific toward your question and go to this link. Your question is explained here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252497/java-8-streams-compare-two-lists-object-values-and-add-value-to-new-list

Comment: Hi sorry for the inconvenience, now added additional information to the question. kindly help me with this.

Comment: @SheshanathKumar i am not going to store values using it, just need to compare values from two different list, based on the constraint i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: One approach would be to zip the two streams and filter on any where they match.  There's nothing built-in for this, but there are ways to do it, including third-party libraries.  I would take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip.

Comment: Does the operation you want to perform need the matching element from the first list, the matching element from the second list, the name, or the index?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a third-party library that has the ability to [zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_(computer_science)) pairs of streams into a single stream of pairs.  Using this approach, the two streams would be zipped into a single stream containing the pairs of elements, the pairs with equal names would be retained via a call to [`Stream.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)), and then finally the remaining filtered pairs of elements will have the action applied to them.

The Stack Overflow answer [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip) contains various solutions for zipping two streams in this manner.

### Guava

Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library provides the [`Streams.zip`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.function.BiFunction)) method:

```java
Streams.zip(list1.stream(), list2.stream(), Map::entry)
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().getName().equals(e.getValue().getName()))
        .forEachOrdered(e ->
                System.out.println("Match: " + e.getKey() + ", " + e.getValue()));
```

### StreamEx

The [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library provides multiple zip methods, including [`StreamEx.zip`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#zip(java.util.List,java.util.List,java.util.function.BiFunction)) and [`EntryStream.zip`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#zip(java.util.List,java.util.List)):

```java
EntryStream.zip(list1, list2)
        .filterKeyValue((k, v) -> k.getName().equals(v.getName()))
        .forKeyValue((k, v) -> System.out.println("Match: " + k + ", " + v));
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to stream over the indexes rather than the lists, and use [`List.get(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#get(int)) to retrieve elements from each `List`.

```java
IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(list1.get(i), list2.get(i)))
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().getName().equals(e.getValue().getName()))
        .forEachOrdered(e ->
                System.out.println("Match: " + e.getKey() + ", " + e.getValue()));
```

or

```java
IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
        .filter(i -> list1.get(i).getName().equals(list2.get(i).getName()))
        .forEachOrdered(i ->
                System.out.printf("Match at index %s: %s, %s\n", i, list1.get(i), list2.get(i)));
```

Note for this approach to be efficient, the lists must support fast (e.g. constant-time) random access.  This would generally mean any list which implements the [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface, such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)).